# How do I properly assert a function with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

```
def get_active_campaign_sheets():
   filePath = '//BMG-FPS01/Digital/*****/performance.csv'
   assert os.path.isfile(filePath)
   mapping_df = pd.read_csv(filePath)
```

So I have this sample code here, but I keep getting an assertion error. I was wondering how would I properly assert this file to use with the pandas module

Comment: @enzo On Unix-based systems, at least, the two slashes will get coerced to one without issue (I just tested this on my box).

Comment: " but I keep getting an assertion error. " well, be because `'//BMG-FPS01/Digital/*****/performance.csv'` is not a path to a file... are the asterisks really there?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I'm so sorry!!!

Comment: @enzo No worries! StackOverflow is a learning experience for every one of us. :)